# In Rust, how can I ensure that two different parameters have the same reference type, either & or &mut?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a binary tree data structure, and I have written a traversal function like this:

```rust
    fn pre_traverse<F>(&mut self, mut visit: F)
    where
        F: FnMut(&mut T),
    {
        let mut stack = vec![self];
        while let Some(tree) = stack.pop() {
            if let Some(node) = &mut tree.root {
                visit(&mut node.data);
                stack.push(&mut node.right);
                stack.push(&mut node.left);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `pre_traverse` function is a higher-order function because I need the `visit` function to operate on nodes in my tree.

However, there's a problem. As you can see, both the function parameter `self` and the `visit` parameter `T` have been declared as `&mut`. If my `visit` function only needs to read the node (e.g., traverse the tree and calculate the tree node size), this mutability requirement may be unnecessary.

Is there a way to specify whether the reference should be `&` or `&mut` when I use the `pre_traverse` function, like this (using `RefType` to specify the reference type)?

```rust
    fn pre_traverse<F>(RefType self, mut visit: F)
    where
        F: FnMut(RefType T),
    {
        let mut stack = vec![self];
        while let Some(tree) = stack.pop() {
            if let Some(node) = RefType tree.root {
                visit(RefType node.data);
                stack.push(RefType node.right);
                stack.push(RefType node.left);
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that I can write two separate functions, one for &mut and one for &, but this approach is not very elegant. I'm asking here to see if there might be a possible solution.

Comment: No, there is no way to abstract over mutability. You need to duplicate the function (you can use a macro to help with that).

Comment: Technically, it is possible to write such abstraction... But it probably won't be worth it.